# Wrong decimal after updating EF Core and .NET from 6 to 7

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0

My server is delivering totally wrong data since I updated the framework and EF Core from 6 to 7.

I also had to change the Docker environment to a .NET 7 one.

Not the problem.

My input is:

```
<tr>
    <td>23:06</td>
    <td>
        <a href="/profil/123456-Username" title="Username">Username</a>
    </td>
    <td>Payment </td>
    <td align="right">0,17 &euro;</td>
</tr>
```

It's all about the last line:

```
<td align="right">0,17 &euro;</td>
```

I want to save this in my database, with:

```
Payment paymentDataData = new Payment()
                {
                    RowIndex = rowindex,
                    Time = Convert.ToDateTime(columns[0].InnerHtml).TimeOfDay,
                    UserId = Convert.ToInt32(columns[1].ChildNodes[1].Attributes["href"].Value.Split('/')[2].Split('-')[0]),
                    Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(columns[3].InnerHtml.Split(' ')[0], new CultureInfo("de-DE")),
                };
```

but instead of converting it to `0,17`, `Convert.ToDecimal` turns it into `17.00`.

It was running for 2 years now without a problem, but now I got wrong data in the database.

It is running fine on my local machine. What could cause the problem only on my server and how could I solve it?

Comment: That doesn't repro for me.  You'll need to create a short, self-contained repro of the issue and add it to your question.  But likely you'll figure it out along the way.

Comment: Could you please confirm, are there any browser culture configured on your server?